# Bottom Border of first row disappears when table is scrolled down

Tags: css

I need the help of the experts on this one.

How can the code be modified in the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JDn7j/ or css to correct the bottom border from disappearing when the table is scrolled down. I am guessing that for consistency, the 2 row, top border should be removed only.

How do I do this?

```
<style type="text/css">
div.scrollTableContainer thead tr   {
    top: expression(offsetParent.scrollTop);
    left: expression(typeof(myvar) == 'undefined' ? 0+"px"+(myvar='true') : -1+"px");
}
table.dataTable {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
}
table.dataTable th {
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 4px 3px 3px 4px;
    background: #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
}

table.dataTable td {
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: 1px solid #999; 
    padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
}


div.scrollTableContainer {
    height: 285px;  
    overflow: auto;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
}


div.scrollTableContainer table {
    width: 952px;
}

div.scrollTableContainer thead tr   {
    position:relative;
}

div.scrollTableContainer td:last-child {padding-right: 20px;}

</style>
```

Comment: I don't see the issue you're describing?

Comment: Using IE 7 if that helps.

Comment: Using IE 7 *rarely* helps... =)

Comment: Yeah I don't see your issue either with Chrome

Comment: You either need to change the behavior of the scroll (so that it always scrolls in multiples of the row-height), or move the border from the table to the div so that it is always shown (you'll probably want to hide the overflow-x).

Comment: Ok, what would be the css code to remove just only the top row border of the 1st row after the table headers?

Comment: div.scrollTableContainer tr:first-child td { border-top: 0; }

div.scrollTableContainer thead th {border-bottom: 1px solid #999; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want a consistent bottom border? 
Assuming I understand your question correctly...

Add border-bottom: 1px solid black to the container 
and remove border-bottom from the last row. 
th:last-child { border-bottom: 0 }